# How to design a database to efficiently support multiple key query?

Tags: database, b-tree

A database stores employee's name, age, salary and address.

I know that if it is single key query, then B+ tree is the choice.
What about multiple key query, for example, I want to know all employees with last name Smith and age greater than 40. How to support this kind of query efficiently?

My current idea is to create a B+ tree for each key, which costs extra space.
Also I need to find intersection of the results returned by each B+ tree query, and this costs extra runtime.

I am new to database, and any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach is usually to create index for every attribute you need, then get result from each of them and do intersection, just as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! Any better approach to skip the intersection part?

Comment: If you know exactly what query you are going to ask, you can do for example some clever sorting. If you create and index by name, and the same names are sorted according to age, then once you get your Smiths, it's easy to just choose the part of age > 40. In case you choose more names, you can then merge sort them according to age and again, choose the part easily.

Answer (score 1):

I think a compound index will be the best choice. It would be an index that stores name and age data. So when traversing the tree, after finding a match on the name the pending results will be all of the Smith ones that will also be ordered by age too.

So, the total cost would be the time it takes to find the first Smith plus the time that it takes to find the last Smith whose age is 40 or less.

Comment: Thanks! But what if you do not know what queries will look like before hand? For instance, I need to know all employees living in California, age > 35 and salary > 1000. The compound index solution does not work well in that case.

Answer (score 0):

By B+ tree, I assume you mean creating indexes. The general rule is to only create an index when the key(s) are 95% unique. Some query optimizers ignore indexes that do not follow this rule. These uesless indexes cost time on insertion and space and should be avoided - they can also confuse some optimizers.

Comment: 95% unique, you mean for every 100 values there are only 5 duplicates? I couldn't disagree more and depending on the number indexes needed may even suggest inverting that number. If you have a 1m row table with 10k possible values in a column each value has an average of 10k records associated with it, i.e. 0.01% of the table. You're suggesting scanning the entire table rather than a tiny fraction.

Comment: Correct. 95%. I am not suggesting it, but just relating the rule that optimizers follow. I did not pull this number out of my hat, so I suggest you do a little more research before declaring it untrue.  What is really suggests it that b-tree's incur enough overhead to justify table scans over index look-ups.

Comment: I'm sorry but I just can't agree; I think you've got this the wrong way around. If an value is _more than_ 5-10% of a column then yes, most optimizers will ignore it as it's quicker to do a full table scan, i.e. there's < 10 to 20 values per 100. We could of course be talking at complete cross purposes about different RDBMS...

Comment: @Ben: It's trivially easy to test. PostgreSQL and the other 5 database engines I run here for testing all use indexes for columns that have only 3 distinct values in 5k rows.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, I agree with you, based on testing. Nothing special about the tests, just a CREATE INDEX... statement after testing performance without an index.